# Finding a threshold value by iterating through data

Tags: sql, postgresql

The table "Files" looks as follows:

```
File (
    id    (varchar);  
    size (double);
    status (varchar);
    timestamp (date);
)
```

I would like to formulate an SQL query that determines the earliest date (timestamp) when all files with that and earlier timestamps have:

1. total size greater than a certain default value and
2. status equal to "processed"

Something like:

```
select MIN(timestamp)
from File
where status = "processed"
 and SUM(size) > 1456,98
```

The problem is this part with the operator `SUM`, it should be applied on the sizes of all files with timestamp either equal or earlier than the timestamp that should be actually returned by this query.
Is it possible to make such an SQL query at all?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

In ANSI standard SQL, you would use window functions:

```
select min(timestamp)
from (select t.*,
             sum(size) over (order by timestamp) as cumesize
      from files f
     ) f
where cumsize > 1456.98 and
      status = 'processed';
```

Note:  This counts the sizes of all files.  If you want the sum of the sizes of only processed files, then move the status condition to the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

If your dbms doesn't support window functions:

```
select MIN(timestamp)
from File f1
where status = "processed"
 and (select SUM(size)
      from File f2
      where f2.timestamp <= f1.timestamp
        and status = "processed") > 1456,98
```